# Can you filter pandas dataframe to get all rows that contain specific pattern like I would do for regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and I am trying to write a pipeline to capture all ID's that have "R" and "yes" in the same row.

I have multiple csv files that contains the following pattern:

CSVFile1

```
"ID1","R","","","","","yes"
"ID2","S","","","","","yes"
```

CSVFile2

```
"ID1","animal","R","","","","","","","","yes"
```

CSVFile3

```
"ID1","animal","fish","S","","","","","","","yes"
"ID2","animal","dog","R","","","","","","","yes"
```

Using regex, I can capture all lines with R and yes:

```
input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

for line in input:
    if re.match(r'^(?=.*(\bR\b)+)(?=.*(\byes\b)+)', line) is not None:
        print (line)
```

But if I convert it to pandas dataframe, is there a way I could capture all rows that have R and yes without having to specify that column names each time, as not all files have the same number of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
print(df[df.eq("R").any(1) & df.eq("yes").any(1)])
```

Output (CSVFile1)

```
     0  1   2   3   4   5    6
0  ID1  R NaN NaN NaN NaN  yes
```

---

```
print(df1[df1.eq("R").any(1) & df1.eq("yes").any(1)])
```

Output (CSVFile2)

```
    0       1    2  3   4   5   6   7   8   9    10
1  ID2  animal  dog  R NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  yes
```

Comment: Thats handy! What does any(1) mean?

Comment: @cms72 `any(axis=1)` is same as `any(1)` , [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) is the docs

Comment: I see! Thank you @Chris and @anky_91!